# I found how to change the video source (src) of an html5 source tag but am getting different results inside a function or with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video

Javascript to change the src of a  tag works inline, but when I try to embed the exact same code in a function call or within an "onclick" call of a button tag, noting happens. No error messages are thrown.

What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
 <div style="width: 100%; height: 250px; overflow: hidden;">
  <video id="video" width="100%" loop autoplay controls>
  <source id="videoSource" src="video1.m4v" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>

<script language="Javascript">
    document.getElementById('video').volume=0;
   // uncommented, the next line works, changing the video src to a new URL     
   // document.getElementById('videoSource').src = "video2.m4v";
    function changevideo() { 
        alert("Changing Video");
    // but embedded in a function or called from a button onclick, does not work
    document.getElementById('videoSource').src = "video2.m4v";
    }       
</script>

<div>
 <button onclick="javascript: changevideo()">Change Movie</button>
</div>
```

I've tested on Safari and Chrome on a Mac with same results. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're not binding `changevideo` to a click event listener.

Comment: simply because there is nothing to click.

Comment: could you add the code where you have done it onclick

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear. I have amended the code snippet in my question to include the button onclick that calls the changevideo() function. The function executes a .src assignment but when done inside the function, does not work. When done inline (inside <script> tags), the .src assignment works.

Comment: @Alan: [works for me in Chrome 27 and Safari 6 on Mac OS X 10.8](http://jsfiddle.net/ejFYD/).

Answer (score 0):

Use function in the click event inline like this

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 250px; overflow: hidden;">
 <video id="video" width="100%" loop autoplay controls>
  <source id="videoSource" src="video1.m4v" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>


<div>
 <button onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('videoSource').src = 'video2.m4v'">Change Movie</button>
</div>
```

Or you can use jquery event bindings. This is a better way.

In your method in some browsers the changevideo function will be undefined I think

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the source tag ID, use video ID. It works for me!

`function changevideo() {
  document.getElementById('video').src = "video2.m4v";
}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but `language` is a deprecated attribute for `script` tag ([W3C: Scripts in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html)).

Use `type="text/javascript"` instead or do not use any attribute, since `type="text/javascript"` is the default value.